# Better way to wrap specific Word of div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to simply turn the word 'login' from "Please login to comment" into a hyperlink, with the URL being the href from `.wpd-login`.

I've got it technically working but JSFiddle is acting like this is incorrect syntax. is there a better way to do this task?

```js
var URL = 'https://example.com/?s_login_popup';

$(".wpd-login-to-comment").each(function() {
  //$(this).html($(this).html().replace(/login/g, "<strong>login</strong>"));
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/login/g, "<a href="
    ' + URL + '
    ">login</strong>"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wpd-login-to-comment">Please login to comment</div>

<div class="wpd-login">
  <a href="https://example.com/?s_login_popup"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Login</a> </div>
```

Comment: You're mixing up your Single and Double Quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Make one minor change:

```
var URL = 'https://example.com/?s_login_popup';
$(".wpd-login-to-comment").each(function(i, el) {
  $(el).html($(el).text().replace(/login/g, "<a href='" + URL + "'>login</a>"));
});
```

Since you're using `"` to build your HTML String, you need to ensure they are being used properly.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/hc5dvmk3/4/

Answer (score 0):

```js
var URL = 'https://example.com/?s_login_popup';

$(".wpd-login-to-comment").each(function() {
    //$(this).html($(this).html().replace(/login/g, "<strong>login</strong>"));
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/login/g, "<a href="+ URL +">login</strong>"));
});
```

```html
<div class="wpd-login-to-comment">Please login to comment</div>
<div class="wpd-login">
    <a href="https://example.com/?s_login_popup">
    <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Login</a>            
</div>    
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```